# Does infravision do anything useful?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced, baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

There are several items, races, and even a spell that can give a character infravision. However, all this seems to do is make creatures display in red if they stand in darkness.

Does infravision provide any actual bonus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having finished both games, they do not provide any benefit other than making it easier to identify characters in the UI. Since the UI already surrounds everything in a blue circle, this isn't particularly valuable.

Comment: There is a stream achievement for using Infravision - this may or may not count as useful depending on how you view them.